# other session not generated when ASP.NET_SessionId timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am trying to regenerate the `ASP.NET_SessionId`. For doing so I am setting expiry days to -30 days and declaring one more session named `Session["IsAuntheticated"]` and setting it to `true`. And after that I am redirecting my page to another page. Code sample is as follows:

```
 Session.Abandon(); // Session Expire but cookie do exist
 Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
 Session["IsAuntheticated"] = "true";
 Response.Redirect("/Webforms/Administration/Default.aspx", false);
```

And I am checking `Session["IsAuntheticated"]` in default page like this

```
 if (Session["IsAuntheticated"] == null)
 {
      //doing something
 }
```

When I debug, every time  I am getting null value of `Session["IsAuntheticated"]`.

My requirement is to regenerate `ASP.NET_SessionId` by keeping the same value of other sessions for fixing the bug of Session Hijacking in visual studio 2008. How can I do this? I have tried [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/899918).

As far as I know this is because of expiry of `ASP.NET_SessionId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the code below I hope this one helps.

```
Session.Clear(); // Session Expire but cookie do exist
```

`Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires =DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);`
        `Session["IsAuntheticated"] = "true";`
        `Response.Redirect("/Webforms/Administration/Default.aspx", false);`